# You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play-Upload apk to google play

Tags: android, upload, google-play, apk

I Want to upload my apk to google play store.but its Show me error like this.

```
**You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play**
```

and than i searched for this and i receive suggetion to change the ***android:debuggable="false"*** in manifast.xml.

I changed like this

manifast.xml

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Concall"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

and in my build.grable(Module)

```
android {
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable false
    }
}
```

1.is the enough for upload Apk to google play store?

2.if i pick up apk from my project folder(app>>build>>output>>apk>>apk-debug.apk) after this change than after it will able to upload in google play store??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as of right answer found

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't use the **debug** variant output! Build a **release** apk. You can do that in Android Studio by going to the menu Build -> Generate Signed APK. Or by executing ./gradlew assembleRelease if you have properly configured signing in the build file.

Comment: Yes, remove all that. No need to deal with this "debuggable" thing anywhere. The "debug" build type will automatically be debuggable and the "release" build type will automatically be non-debuggable.

Comment: yes i remove that.But apk ( picked up from app>>build>>output>>apk>>apk-debug.apk ) which i use to upload is the able to Upload to Play Store? @niqueco

Comment: No, you are not building a "release" version. The release version will be at app/app-release.apk ... It won't be inside build/output. Try the menu optjon I mention in the answer (you'll need to have signing set up already for this to work).

Comment: @niqueco The release version will be at app/app-release.apk if you keep the default location value, but you can specify the location you want.

Comment: @niqueco I have to debug the released .apk I have to check the issues in the app and want to export the offline DB from the published app from the client tablet. What should I do?

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad Sorry, I've never tried to debug a release apk. I've never had the need to do that. To export the db you can sideload the apk to the emulator and use Android Studio's "device file explorer" to navigate to the db file and get it. If you don't use the emulator I think Android will deny access to the file.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this error and my application did not reference `debuggable` anywhere. After a little bit of searching, I found that I accidentally had `testCoverageEnabled true` in my `release` build type.

```
release {
    testCoverageEnabled true
    ...
}
```

Removing this resolved the issue.

Comment: Ugh... mixture of happy to have finally found this, and frustration that some of the android gradle config is so unintuitive

Answer (score 10):

In my build.gradle file, I had `debuggable = false` and I was wondering why I'm getting this issue. later I found that it was `debuggable = true` in my AndroidManifest.xml file's application tag

Comment: Thanks, that was makin' me crazy. I set it to false in the build.gradle and removed it from the build.gradle and still it said it was debuggable when I uploaded it.  I don't know how long it would have taken without you answer.

Comment: @MarkDail Glad it helps you.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem. Unknowingly I kept

> debuggable true in release buildType

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
```

After changed to false. Its working fine.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This feature can be controlled from the manifest file also, disable from there

```
android:debuggable="false
```

Comment: This solution works better for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the flags for uploading the `Apk` to `Playstore`. Not needed to be release build. If you want to test your `qa` build, you can do ./gradlew assembleQa
with flags

```
minifyEnabled true
debuggable false
shrinkResources true
testCoverageEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this warning when I wasn't selecting the "Signed" version.In the signed version, select release to deploy.

[image: Non-signed "Debug" version vs. Signed version].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you add set `debuggable="true"` . you can remove code that or set to `false`

If you not find in `build.gradle` you can check in ***AndroidManifest***