# Google Play Store - Disable debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, playback, mode

Can you please help me?

I try upload my application for google play store, and this problem:
"**You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play**

What this need setting? Thank you very mutch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the debug variant output! Build a release apk. You can do that in Android Studio by going to the menu Build -> Generate Signed APK.

Comment: partial copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263949/you-uploaded-a-debuggable-apk-for-security-reasons-you-need-to-disable-debuggin#answer-32264355), not nice

Comment: thank you!

Only 1 thing: another problem for google store upload:

"You must use another package name because "appteve.com.castio" already exists on Google Play."

Now what is needed? 
Thank you!!!

Comment: But I want to export the offline SQLite DB from the client's published app to resolve sync issues in the app. What steps have to taken?