# Publish Unity android game on Google Play problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I have problem with publish android game on Google Play, when i upload .aab file i see:
**You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play**.
I found this: [You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play-Upload apk to google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263949/you-uploaded-a-debuggable-apk-for-security-reasons-you-need-to-disable-debuggin) but I don't know how to fix my app in Unity 2021.

Mayby someone know how to fix it

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your build Settings Go to File>Build Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if these options are as follows:
Open the Build Settings: file > build settings (Ctrl+Shift+B)
Check the option Build App Bundle (Google Play)
And uncheck the option Development Build
Generate the .aab file again.
[as in the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QUba.png)